# git svn fetch does not update a recently created branch

Tags: git, git-svn

I just recently created a branch in our subversion repository. Running git-svn does not see the branch for some reason. The only thing that I can think of is that the trunk is behind the branch because there have been no commits on the trunk since the branch was created.

Comment: How is your SVN repo organized?  Using the standard trunk, branches, tags format?

Comment: Yes, the repo is in the standard format.

Comment: What command did you use to clone the repository?  (Please include the path)

Comment: git svn clone --stdlayout svn://path_to_repo local_directory

Comment: Does path_to_repo include the word trunk?

Comment: Apologies for the extremely late reply, I missed your comment. No, path_to_repo does not contain the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to open your repository with SmartGit and try to fetch from it. It is git-svn-compatible, but based on another engine, so probably doesn't have this bug (if it is a bug).

If it won't help it is more likely that something is wrong with your project configuration/layout.

Answer (score -1):

If your svn repo's layout is like this,

```
  https://server/repo/trunk
  https://server/repo/branch1
  https://server/repo/branch2
```

Then add these to your .git/config,

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svn/repo
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
[svn-remote "branch1"]
    url = https://svn/repo
    fetch = branch1:refs/remotes/branch1
[svn-remote "branch2"]
    url = https://svn/repo
    fetch = branch2:refs/remotes/branch2
```

```
% git svn fetch svn 
% git svn fetch branch1
% git svn fetch branch2
```

Comment: -1 That doesn't explain or solve the OP's issue (where the branch should have been *automatically* picked up), and there are far simpler work-arounds to that Subversion structure, namely specifying each branch as a separate `svn-remote.svn.fetch`. Specifying each branch as an entirely separate repository is just painful.